# Retrieve the count of datarows where a column has a value

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a DataTable with a column named `ContainerTitle`.  I would like to get the count of the number of rows in the DataTable where the `ContainerTitle` has a particular value. For example, lets say the DataTable has 16 rows where `ContainerTitle = "Widget1"` and 10 rows where `ContainerTitle = "Widget2"`.  I would like to query to get the count of rows where `ContainerTitle = "Widget1"`.  Later, when done processing those rows, I would like to get the count of rows where `ContainerTitle = "Widget2"`.  I can't figure out how to get the count.

This is what I have come up with so far where the code is incrementing through the datarows:

```
for(int i=0;i<dt.Rows.Count;i++)
{
    DataRow dr = dt.Rows[i];
    szContainerName = dr["ContainerTitle"].ToString();

    // here is where I am attempting to get the count
    var tst = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(p => p.Field<string>("ContainerTitle") == szContainerName );

    .
    .
    .
    if (szContainerName != szPrevContainerName)
    {
        szPrevContainerName= szContainerName ;
    }

}
```

Comment: It's called "LINQ" (Language-Integrated Query)

Comment: 50% on the spelling test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would take the predicate, you can use it like:

```
var count = dt
           .AsEnumerable()
           .Count(p => p.Field<string>("ContainerTitle") == szContainerName );
```

You can also add `Count` to your where clause like:

```
var count = dt
           .AsEnumerable()
           .Where(p => p.Field<string>("ContainerTitle") == szContainerName );
           .Count();
```

Comment: My problem was that I was missing the using System.Linq namespace.

Comment: @LeeZ, how you were able to compile with `Where` ?

Comment: I "inherited" the code today and it is missing some important items.  The code dynamically renders HTML content and is missing colspans leading to whitespace.  Where does popup in intellisense without the using.